# ssl.SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3837)

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, ssl-certificate, client-certificates, pem

Trying to connect to a server through TLS/SSL connection.

I have searched on StackOverflow but could not find the answer 
also to make sure certfile & private key matches

I have checked 
https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-key-matcher.html

and it gives me

The certificate and private key match!

Certificate Hash:
3fe39d1c76d2802002741d0660dea5d7ffb6e170b5fdxxxxxxxxxx

Key Hash:
3fe39d1c76d2802002741d0660dea5d7ffb6e170b5fdxxxxxxxxxx

I tried .crt & .pem & did not work

the error

```
 context.load_cert_chain(certfile=client_cert, keyfile=clients_key, 
 password=None)
 ssl.SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3837)
```

code:-

```
def tlstest():


     hostAddress = 'x'
     hostPort = xxxx
     serverHostName = 'x.com'

      client_cert = 'D:\ssl\client.pem'
      clients_key = 'D:\ssl\clientKey.pem'

      context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)

      context.load_cert_chain(certfile=client_cert, keyfile=clients_key,
                        password=None)

      context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
```

Comment: Works perfectly for me with my own files which suggests that this is a problem with your specific files. Please provide the actual `client.pem` and `clientKey.pem` files  which show the problem.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich for clientkey 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1C1jYYbEedX3fvV36XAhvyLRlHJgkM1gk

for client pem
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fowhgdXdplpKZJNHJ9s5SphRJxWWlr1L

Comment: Your key file has **extraneous empty lines** following each valid line (except the last). This is not valid PEM format. I'll guess the sslshopper website accepts improper whitespace because cut&paste often alters whitespace, and they want to help naive users who might not be able to fix this.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks a lot it gives new issue now 

ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)

I have made sure to download certifi through pip but still gives this new error I will search on it

Comment: That error is about the cert or chain **from the server**. Look at the server config, or look at what it sends with e.g. `openssl s_client -connect host:port -showcerts` (below 1.1.0 may need `-servername host` depending on server) or Java's `keytool -printcert -sslserver host[:port]` or nmap or many other tools. Or if you want _us_ to look at and it's publicly reachable, identify it.